# Why does my music hang/freeze/glitch?

Tags: 16.04, music, clementine

I like to listen to music on my laptop when I am working. Often I face the issue of music hanging/stops/interruptions while doing simple (non compute intensive) tasks such as editing text files or browsing web. It is very annoying.

My laptop has Core-i5 450M processor and 4 GB of RAM which I think is more than decent to perform simple tasks. I am wondering what is the reason for the glitches in music playback. Is it an Ubuntu issue or my Hardware isn't fast enough?

Comment: Your hardware is fast enough, for sure. Nearly all computers today are fast enough to flawlessly process audio. So your problem is your Operating System or the software.

Comment: I'm been using Ubuntu 16.04 for more than a year now (Before that I used Linux Mint which is also a Debian based distro). I wonder if the glitch in music playback is due to poor multitasking software.

Comment: Have you tried other music players besides Clementine? How long has the issue been occurring? Does it affect all music and all formats (MP3, FLAC, OGG, etc)? Regarding hardware, a first-gen Core is a bit old, but still fine. I'd be more concerned about your hard disk, especially if it's as old as the CPU; you might want to [check its SMART data](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en).

Comment: Before clementine I used the default music player packaged with mate 16.04. As for the SMART it says `SMART Disk Health Good: yes` and `Overall Status: BAD_SECTOR`